# How to check if a svg element exists or not using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, svg

I have a svg map which has a few elements like rect, circle, line, text and so on. I need to check whether a particular circle element exists or not. It fails at the findElement method itself i.e am unable to locate the element using code. When I inspect element and enter my xpath in chrome, I get the element but when I use this xpath in selenium java code, it cannot locate the element. I tried the following:

1. exists=driver.findElements(by).size() != 0;
2. findElements method with xpath and cssSelector

DOM structure:

```
<circle cx="499.99999999999653" cy="199.00000000000082" r="8" fill="#0000ff" stroke="#ffffff" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></circle><rect x="459.99999999999653" y="206.00000000000082" width="80" height="10" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0" opacity="0.65" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.65;"></rect><text x="499.99999999999653" y="211.00000000000082" text-anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; font: bold 10px &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;;" font-weight="bold" font-family="Trebuchet MS"><tspan dy="3.4453125000008242" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Node 4 Object</tspan></text>
```

Xpath used :
//*[name()="svg"]//*[name()="text"]//*[name()="tspan" and text()="Node 4 Object"]//../preceding-sibling::*[position()=2]

Comment: What paths did you use?

Comment: //*[name()="svg"]//*[name()="text"]//*[name()="tspan" and text()="Node 4 Object"]//../preceding-sibling::*[position()=2]